# How to save and edit documents in cluster and online archive connection

Tags: mongodb

I recently used auto-archival option for some of my collection, and found that there are now three connection strings.
My code was written to use one string and was doing read and create or update queries on same connection object.
Now after archiving , I have to update my code to use two connections objects.
As, cluster and online archive is read only.

Is there any other solution, to query read and create or update on same connection string ?

Thanks